# How to run npm script in visual studio code launch.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run the follwowing npm script in Visual Studio code's launch.json file:

`nodemon src/shim-host/index.js --exec babel-node --babel-preset-es2015`

My attempt so far in my `launch.json` file:

`"program": "nodemon src/shim-host/index.js --exec babel-node --babel-preset-es2015",`

However, I am getting the error `"Attribute 'program' is not absolute'"`

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program attribute is your code and nodemon should be the runtimeExecutable.

Example from [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_restarting-debug-sessions-automatically-when-source-is-edited):

```
{
    "name": "Launch server.js via nodemon",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--debug=5858"
    ],
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",
    "restart": true,
    "port": 5858,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```